# Adjunction algebra - is there anything similar to this in algebra?

Tags: universal-algebra

I call ***adjunction algebra*** a universal algebra with one binary operation denoted as the punctuation sign (**;**) "semicolon" (but I will be using only one space after it, not on both sides - to avoid going against the regular punctuation practice and creating typographical problems), and 3 axioms which are universal closures of these formulas (between brackets I indicate how I refer to them):

- $((x; y); y) = (x; y)$  [right idempotency]
- $((x; y); z) = ((x; z); y)$ [right commutativity]
- $((x; y); z) = (x; y) \rightarrow ((x; z) = x \vee z = y)$ [right
  atomicity]

I call *normal* or *normalized* adjunction algebra, an algebra which additionally to adjunction has a constant $0$ such that:

- $(0; x) \ne x$

I think, this algebra is important for algebraization of set theory. Also, for several years now, I am using it, in another presentation, in my research of semantics of natural languages. I used to call the operation (;) "qualification", because it explains the semantics of qualified names in computer science. Lately, I learnt that this operation is called "adjunction" from @Joel's answer to my [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173678/is-there-one-binary-operation-foundational-for-set-theory). The axioms above are from the [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1257862036#first-page) by Kirby referenced there. True, Kirby does not call this "adjunction algebra", because along these axioms Kirby also uses an induction axiom and he studies a "theory", not an "algebra".

The intended interpretation in set theory of the $(x; y)$ is $x \cup  ${$y$}, and in this interpretation $(x; y) = x$ iff $y \ \epsilon \ x$.  This shows why adjunction is important for set theory - set theory can be presented in the language of one operation. In Kirby's paper the operation of union is defined by induction (which is an axiom) and it sounds to me improbable that it can be defined through ";" an "0" without such an axiom.

Here are some of my questions:

(1) Does the axioms above occur in abstract algebra and what are the names of the properties they express?

(2) Is what I call normal adjunction algebra "free" in some sense (my algebraic background is not very strong, so my question might not be precise).

(3) Are there algebras where the induction principle, in any of its different forms, is represented algebraically (i.e. as identities or quasiidentities)?

Comment: In right atomicity shouldn't one of the consequents be (x; z) =x ?

Comment: An example of a non-free normal adjunction algebra: consider the set with 2 elements $\{0, 1\}$, with the operation $;$ defined as $0; 1=0$, $0; 0=1$, $1; 1=1$, $a; b=b; a$. This seems to me to yield a normal adjunction algebra, and it is certainly not free.

Comment: I've deleted a nonsensical comment. Since your axioms for adjunction algebras include a non-equation, there doesn't seem to be a nice way to build a free algebra: "free on $n$ generators" should mean "epis onto anything $n$-generated," but it's not obvious how to build one (or even if there are any), and of course this is even more true for normal adjunction algebras. On the other hand, a finite adjunction algebra certainly won't be free, so I've left my second comment intact.

Comment: Since the axioms of a universal algebra generally don't have non-equations, probably, the definition of a normal adjunction algebra should be different: "An adjuction algebra is said to be *normal* if it has an element $0$, such that the $(0; x) \ne 0$" (that is a constant $0$ for such an element is not included in the signature of the algebra). Then the question (2) sounds to make more sense.

Comment: How does that change anything? The problem is not in the definition of normality. The problem is that the "right atomicity" axiom is not an equation.

Comment: It seems to me like a far more natural notion would be to fix a set $A$ and consider algebras which are sets $P$ together with operations $P\times A\to P$ satisfying (some of) your axioms.  If you use only the first two axioms, the free algebra on one generator is the set of finite subsets of $A$.

Comment: This sounds interesting, especially when the set A is transitive (contains elements of its elements) or, moreover, is closed under different useful set theoretic operations, say A is a Grothendieck universe. Is not then right that A is generated by the empty set and sets whose cardinality is a limit cardinal, which can be called "atoms". But what you defined is not quite "algebras". Can you please put this down in more detail in an answer?

Comment: My point is merely that your axioms can be interpreted just as well in a two-sorted structure: nothing about them lets you identify "sets" (elements of $P$) with their "elements" (elements of $A$).  As you originally stated your axioms, there is only a single sort, but all this is saying is that we have arbitrarily chosen some bijection between $P$ and $A$.  Furthermore, once you separate $P$ and $A$, then you really just have a set $P$ with a unary operation on it for each element of $A$, which is why I suggest fixing $A$.

Comment: I am missing something, and I don't know how to do this. So, we talk about an algebra with only "right idempotency" and "right commutativity". How this algebra can be defined in the manner you suggest?